# Why does the product of the eigenvector and the corresponding eigenvalue not equal the product of the original matrix and the eigenvector?

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, eigenvalue, eigenvector

When I multiply an eigenvector by a matrix, it should result in the same output as multiplying that eigenvector by its corresponding eigenvalue. I am trying to verify that my eigenvectors and eigenvalues are working as advertised, but the outputs don't seem right.

```
cov_matrix = np.cov(scaled_data)
eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eigh(cov_matrix)

a = cov_matrix.dot(eig_vecs[:, 0])
b = eig_vecs[:, 0] * eig_vals[0]
```

When I print a and b, they are the same shape but their values are all different. What is going wrong here?

Comment: the column eig_vecs[:, i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue eig_vals[i], not the row eig_vecs[i]

Comment: Thank you! I edited the code (possibly incorrectly but not sure) to correct for this but a and b are still returning differing vectors.

Comment: notice `np.linalg.eigh` works only on "complex Hermitian (conjugate symmetric) or a real symmetric matrix" (taken from documentation). Are you sure your matrix is symmetric? If so, please provide concrete example for `scaled_data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following :

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42) # for reproducibility
A = np.random.random((10,10)) + np.random.random((10,10)) * 1j
eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eigh(A)

np.allclose(A @ eig_vecs[:, 0], eig_vals[0] * eig_vecs[:, 0])
>>> False
```

Keep in mind that [np.linalg.eigh](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html) return the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a complex Hermitian (conjugate symmetric) or a real symmetric matrix. So for a hermitian matrix:

```
A = (A + A.T.conj())/2  # Here A is forced Hermitian now
eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eigh(A)

print(np.allclose(A @ eig_vecs[:, 0], eig_vals[0] * eig_vecs[:, 0]))
>>> True
```

Check prior to diagonalization if `cov_matrix` is symmetric with something like `np.allclose(cov_matrix, cov_matrix.T.conj())`. If not, you can just use [np.linalg.eig](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html).

Comment: `cov_matrix` is indeed symmetric, I checked with your suggestion of using `np.allclose(cov_matrix, cov_matrix.T)`. Also, when substituting `A = np.random.random((10,10))` with `A=cov_matrix`, your code returned true. I think there's something wrong with the way I'm checking the values.

Comment: I was doing `print(a[0])`, `print(b[0])` and `print(a[0] == b[0])`, with the idea that the values would be identical, but this must be misguided somehow.

Comment: Okay, I figured out the problem, which actually related to your initial comment of the columns being the eigenvectors. I was using eig_vecs = eig_vecs[::-1] to flip the list order, which was jumbling all the eigenvectors.  `np.allclose` then confused me for still returning true in some cases, but that was just for negligible eigenvalues so the vectors looked close enough. Thanks so much for your help, I would've stared at this for several more hours.